# Multiple operating systems Installation

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system

How to install 2 operating systems on same hard disk (Or on same system)?
Like I have Windows 10 installed, and want to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Use a search engine first. Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you want is called a 'Dual Boot'. Ubuntu has a guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot. Basically you start installing ubuntu, but choose to resize the windows partition of instead of deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Follow this

Install windows, if already there, go to next step

Install ubuntu, it will ask options like

1) Install ubuntu alongside with windows

2) Install ubuntu, erase everything / other os available

3) Few more options

Select **Install ubuntu alongside with windows**

Proceed with normal installation steps

Next boot your machine, you will see grub asking to choose ubuntu or windows os. 

Select and proceed...